# Expectation of an increasing transformation of a random variable

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose $X$ is real-valued random variable and $\phi$ an increasing function. An **upper set** is either an open or a closed right half line. Below, all expectations are assumed to exist and $I$ denotes the indicator function.

> [Shaked and Shanthikumar (2007)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EKYR7G2) claims the following: it is possible, for each $m$, to define a sequence of upper sets $U_i$'s, a sequence of $a_i$'s, and a $b$ (all of which may depend on $m$), such that as $m\to\infty$,
>   $$
> E\left[\sum_{i=1}^m a_i I_{U_i}(X)\right]-b\to E[\phi(X)]
> $$

I vaguely guess that the Monotone Convergence Theorem is somehow involved but I can't conjure up a construction that does the job. Can you please help me?

Comment: Check how the expectation of a random variable $X$ is defined may help.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I gave that direction some thought but I'm still stumped. :(

Comment: So, think about first $\phi$ is an identity mapping? In this case, we are try to approximate $E(X)$ by simple functions. The idea is the Lebesgue's classic dividing the range. If $\phi$ is a general increasing function, I believe the procedure would be almost the same.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I've thought about that but when you approximate $E(X)$ with linear combinations of simple functions, the supports of those functions are disjoint. In this case, the $U_i$'s will overlap.

Comment: Let's assume $\phi$ is nonnegative and continuous. You can write $\Bbb E[\phi(X)] = \int \Bbb P(X > \phi^{-1}(t))\, dt$ and then approximate the integral by using Riemann-like sums $\sum a_i\, \Bbb P(X > \phi^{-1}(t_i))$. Have you tried this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, $b = - \Bbb E[\phi(X)]$ and $a_1 = \dots = a_m = 0$ is a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a argument similar to the construction of Riemann Stieljes integral via lower sum. Call the function on the left hand side $\psi$
$$
\psi_n(x)=\sum^{m(n)}_{i=1}a_iI_{U_i}(x)-b.
$$
It is important to realize that $\psi_n$ is a step function. For concreteness, let $U_i=[c_i,\infty)$. Relabel the index set so that $c_1<c_2<\ldots<c_m$. Then $\psi_n$ has the following representation ($m$ may depend on $n$)
$$
\psi_n(x)=\sum^m_{i=0}d_iI_{A_i}(x)
$$
where
$$
d_0=-b,\quad d_i=\sum^i_{j=1}(a_i-b),\quad A_0=(-\infty,c_1), \quad,A_i=[c_{i},c_{i+1}),\quad A_m=[c_m,\infty).
$$
Now we can apply the standard simple function approximation to the increasing function $\phi$. Note that for increasing function, Riemann type step function approximation suffices, but we do need to take care of the unbounded support of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral/expectation. As example, consider the following construction
$$
m(n)=2^{3n+1},\quad c_i=-2^n+\frac{i}{2^{2n}},\quad d_0=\sup\phi^{-1}(\lbrace -2^n\rbrace),\quad d_i=\inf_{x\in A_i}\phi(x).
$$
What we are doing is uniformly partitioning the compact interval $[-2^n,2^n]$ and approximate $\phi$ using its infimum on each interval. A little thought should convince you that $\psi_n\uparrow\phi$ pointwise. Note that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, two things must be happening:

1. the compact inverval $[-2^n,2^n]$ needs to expand to cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ eventually.
2. the partition on any fixed compact interval $[-M,M]$ must be finer and finer.

Invoke the probability version of Monotone Convergence Theorem to establish
$$
E[\psi_n(x)]\uparrow E[\phi].
$$
We have to make sure that the sequence $\lbrace \psi_n\rbrace$ is uniformly bounded below. This is ensured by assuming 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\phi(x)>-\infty.
$$
$(a_i,b_i,U_i)$ can be solved back from $(c_i,d_i)$ by our construction and the proof is complete.