# Proof: $Y$ stochastically dominates $X$ implies $E[\phi(Y)]\geq E[\phi(X)]$ for increasing $\phi$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are real random variables with CDF $F$ and $G$ such that $F(x)\geq G(x)$ (i.e. $Y$ exhibits (first-order) stochastic dominance over $X$). Then, for all increasing function $\phi$, we have $E[\phi(Y)]\geq E[\phi(X)]$. I would like to find a rigorous proof of this. Can you please provide one or point me to a reference?

---

For the special case in which both $F$ and $G$ are continuous, one can consider the integral
$$
\int \phi(y)dG(y)
$$
and employ the substitution $y\to\varphi(x)$ where $\varphi(x)\equiv G^{-1}[F(x)]$ to infer that
$$
E[\phi(Y)]=\int\phi(y)dG(y){\color{red}=}\int\phi[\varphi(x)]dF(x)\geq\int\phi(x)dF(x)=E[\phi(X)].
$$
The inequality above is because
$$
F(x)\geq G(x)\implies\varphi(x)=G^{-1}[F(x)]\geq G^{-1}[G(x)]{\color{blue}=}x;\quad \phi\text{ is increasing.}
$$
I've made some attempt for when $F$ and $G$ are general by considering $\varphi(x)=G^*[F(x)]$ where $G^*$ now is the (left-continuous) quantile function of $Y$. I've run into at least 2 problems: (i) I don't think the equality ${\color{red}=}$ above continues to hold; (ii) $G^*[G(x)]\leq x$ so ${\color{blue}=}$ above is turned into $\leq$ which breaks the inequality chain.

A rigorous proof can also follow from a different direction. But this different direction relies on a [construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362793/expectation-of-an-increasing-transformation-of-a-random-variable) I don't know how to do.

Comment: http://www2.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/institute/wt1/research/1996/stochastic_dominance.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to construct a measure $\mu$on an product space $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$ such that $\mu((-\infty,a),\Bbb{R}) = F(a)$ and $\mu(\Bbb{R},(-\infty,b)) = G(b)$ such that $\mu((x,y):  x>y ) = 0$.

Once you have this, then $Y = X + Z$ with $Z\geq 0$ and noting that $\phi$ is increasing

$$\Bbb{E}[\phi(Y)] = \Bbb{E}[\phi(X+Z)] \geq \Bbb{E}[\phi(X)] $$

**claim:** such a $\mu$ exists.

Indeed, consider

$X_n = \sum_{i= 0}^{n-1} \delta_{a^n_i} \frac{1}{n}$ where $a^n_i = \inf\big\{a, F(a)\geq\frac{i}{N}\big\}$ and

$Y_n = \sum_{i= 0}^{n-1} \delta_{b^n_i} \frac{1}{n}$ where $b^n_i = \inf\big\{b, G(b)\geq\frac{i}{n}\big\}$.

Note that $b^n_i \geq a^n_i$. remark also that one might have $a^n_i = a^n_{i+1}$

Construct $\mu^n$ the following way $X^n = a_i^n \Rightarrow Y^n = b_i^n$ (if $X^n = a^n_i$ then $Y^n = b^n_i$). This way $Y^n \geq X^n$.

Now note for every $x$ there is a $k^n(x): \frac{k^n(x)}{n} < F(x) \leq \frac{k^n(x)+1}{n}$

$$F^n(x) = \mu^n(Y^n \leq x) = \frac{\sup\{i, a^n_i \leq x\}}{n} = \frac{k^n(x)}{n}$$

So $X^n\Rightarrow X$ -$X^n$ converges in distribution to $X$ - once the cumulative distributions converge (for every (continuity) point of $F$).

Simmilarly for every $y$ there is a $\tilde{k}^n(y): \frac{\tilde{k}^n(y)}{n} \leq G(y) < \frac{\tilde{k}^n(y)+1}{n}$

$$G^n(y) =\mu^n(Y^n \leq y) = \frac{\sup\{i, b^n_i \leq y\}}{n} = \frac{\tilde{k}^n(y)}{n}$$

So $Y^n\Rightarrow Y$ -$Y^n$ converges in distribution to $Y$ - once the cumulative distributions converge (for every (continuity) point of $G$).

Note further that $\mu^n$ is tight. Indeed let $\alpha$ be such that $F(\alpha)< \epsilon$ and let $\beta$ be such that $G(\beta)> 1 - \epsilon$.

Let $N$ be such that for $n > N$

$$ |F(\alpha) - F^n(\alpha)|< \epsilon\\
|G(\beta) - G^(\beta)| \leq \epsilon $$
Then $$\mu^n((\alpha, \beta)^2) =  1 - \mu^n (X^n \leq \alpha, Y^n \geq \beta) \geq 1 - \mu^n (X^n \leq \alpha) - \mu^n (Y^n \geq \beta) \geq 1 - 4 \epsilon $$

Now, since the sequence of measures is tight (by Prohorov) it admits a limit $\mu$ for some subsequence.

Moreover (by Portemanteau) $\liminf \mu^n(A) \geq \mu(A)$ for every open $A$ 
Take $A = \{(x,y): x>y\}$ and note (to conclude) that $\mu^n(A) = 0$

Comment: Thanks! If you did learn this construction from some source, could you please share it with me?

Comment: I learned it from Peres book on markov chains (Markov Chains and Mixing Times) there in the part where he discusses  coupling. The proof here is more general, and in this form I have never seen. But maybe if you look up for Skorohod representation theorem on Durrett (Probability theory and examples) you will find the technique I employed.

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave me a fish and taught me how to fish. :)

Comment: Does $Y=X+Z$ a.s. with $Z\ge 0$ a.s. mean that $Y\ge X$ a.s.? However, this does not follow from stochastic dominance. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, but notice, for this particular measure $\mu$ we have $Y \geq X$ a.s., in general, X and Y could be independent and such a pointwise relation would not hold. The point is that you can construct an specific $\mu$  where this relation holds almost surely.

Comment: Nice +1d (I missed you comment about coupling)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier proof.

Since increasing functions are differentiable almost surely, we may consider all $\phi$ that is both differentiable and increasing without loss of generality.

Define
$$
H(x)=G(x)-F(x)\leq 0,\quad H(0)=0,\quad \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}H(x)=0.
$$ 
Apply the Integration by Parts for the generalized distribution function
$$
\int \phi(x)dH(x)=[\phi(x)H(x)]^\infty_{0}-\int \phi'(x)H(x-)dx
$$
where
$$
H(x-)=\lim_{t\uparrow x}H(t)\leq 0.
$$
The first term vanishes by construction. The second term is evidently positive. It follows that
$$
\int \phi(x)dG(x)-\int \phi(x)dF(x)=\int \phi(x)dH(x)\geq 0.
$$
This completes the proof.